# Export Azure Templates Programmatically

Tags: c#, azure, templates

Is there a way to export JSon Templates From Existing Azure Objets, 
with C# .Net or Python?

Comment: Do you mean to get the Json ARM Template from the Azure Datacenter, then deploy it ?

Comment: Let's say an existing azure object, can I programmatically extract a json template for later reuse deployement.  ( With C# ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description of a resource group can be got from PowerShell
There is very likey a REST Api behind that can be called with any http client, but PowerShell can be called in C#

```
Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName  my-resource-group
# preceded by Login-AzureRMAccount or storage of credentials in a certificate local to the computer
```

Then from the PowerShell object, you 'll get a `TemplateLink` property that points to the JSon resource description.

Note : the Json resource description has many parameters that need to be provided, so multiple resources can be deployed from the same templates, with different names, different locations, ...

Comment: how is this an answer when question asks for c#